# UITableViewCellAccessory Multiple sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add a checkmark to a `UITableViewCell` when a user selects it. I have the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
```

The table has multiple sections and the problem is that if I select a row the checkmark is duplicated in other rows in different sections. The checkmark also moves between rows in each section as you scroll up and down the page. I have managed to loop through the table and document how many rows have the accessory checkmark and each time it is the number it should be, it doesn't count the other rows that get added without me meaning to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell you set as selected is being reused by the `UITableView` as you scroll up and down the view.

The proper approach is to track selection in a model object or check in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to see if `indexPath` is in the table view's `indexPathsForSelectedRows` and only show the checkmark in that case.  Because `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for both reused and newly created cells, you shouldn't encounter this issue in either scenario.

This assumes you have set `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection` to `YES`.

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = // do some initing here

    // determine if this cell is currently selected
    if ([tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Do you have any sample code? I understand your logic but not the syntax. Thanks again

Comment: It's still producing the same effect. Am I initialising the cell incorrectly?

Comment: @robbiecutting Can you update your question with your current code?  Also check to make sure `indexPathsForSelectedRows` contains the paths you think it should.  If it doesn't, please post all of your `UITableView`-related code.

Comment: Would an easier way to achieve what I need be to use the allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing function? This achieves exactly what I need the only problem is I need to limit the number of selections that can be made at once. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Nothing in your question indicated that you are in edit mode :)  You can certainly set that to `YES` and then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` check the count of `indexPathsForSelectedRows` and refuse the selection if over your limit.  Refusing could be changing `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` to return `nil` or just calling `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]` immediately.

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought. And then just display an alert to the user. I'll mark this question as solved, thanks again for your advice.